# Get the string value of first column cell given another cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Let's say I've got a cell that contains a formula that's selected a cell (i.e. `=j5`). In another cell, I want to have it show the string value of the cell that shares the row of this selected cell, but in a specific column (in this case column `a`), i.e. I want it to show the value of `a5`.

I've tried this: `=INDIRECT("A"&(ROW(D24)))`, but it shows me `0` instead of the string that's in cell `a24`. I thought `INDIRECT` would work since it seems to be the way to build a cell reference manually, but it doesn't seem to be working.

edit: to try to clarify:

[image]

I'm trying to use cell D7 as a 'controller'; I put different cell references in it, e.g. here it's pointing to D3. In D8 is where I want the text to show 'Required Text' automatically.

Comment: Your formula is correct. You are missing something else. Check `A24` value again.

Comment: @Harun24hr I see the issue now; I want the row that d24 itself points to (since it has another cell reference in it).

Comment: Little bit unclear. What value do you have in `D24` cell? What do you mean by `=J5`?

Comment: Can you put a screenshot to make it clear.

Comment: @Harun24hr Added a screenshot to try to explain it better

Comment: Do you mean `=INDIRECT("B"&ROW(INDIRECT(D7)))` or `=INDIRECT("B"&ROW(INDIRECT(RIGHT(FORMULATEXT(D7),LEN(FORMULATEXT(D7))-1))))`?

Answer (score 0):

Pls. check this

`=INDIRECT("K"&ROW(N3))`

[image]